# How to create a file within project folder using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

Hen I create a file in JSP the its created in Apache Bin folder location: apache-tomcat-9.0.65\bin.
I want to create it in project directory. How to create it.

```
 File myObj = new File("test.txt");
 myObj.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
File myDirectory = "/apache-tomcat-9.0.65/bin/";
File myObj = new File(myDirectory, "test.txt");
myObj.createNewFile();
```

if you're using windows you may have to use backslashes instead for the directory (and escape them properly):

```
File myDirectory = "C:\\apache-tomcat-9.0.65\\bin\\";
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Body code file jsp

```
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%
File myObj = new File("test.txt");
myObj.createNewFile();
%>
```

Comment: I am able to create file but the file location is issue. file created in Apache Bin folder location: apache-tomcat-9.0.65\bin. I want to create it in project directory

Comment: You can for the path of the directory directory into that example :
File myObj = new File("/webapp/file/test.txt"); 
//or 
File myObj = new File("webapp/file/test.txt");

Comment: Tested not working, /jsp/mobile/text.txt not working. It is searching this path into apache folder

Comment: You can handle it in a Java class and call it in a jsp